# How to check the column having date in proper format in postgesql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have dataset as like below,

```
01-03-2021
02-04-2021
01-032021
04-05-2021
```

Initially this column is considered as string and i need condition check this column date is greater or lesser than another column in another table.

I can able to perform condition check between two date columns but the case was one row contains invalid date format in dataset "01-032021" i need to avoid that condition check particularly for this type of case row.

my db is postgresql, i tried to ISDATE(column) which is only useful in sql server but not find any function like this in postgresql to check the column is in date format.

Any one suggest me way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can use **pg_typeof (column)**, but if you want to change the column to date format maybe this can help:

SELECT (substring((REPLACE(your_column,'-','')) FROM 1 for 2) || '-' || substring((REPLACE(your_column,'-','')) FROM 3 for 2) || '-' || substring((REPLACE(your_column,'-','')) FROM 5 for 4))::DATE as new_column FROM your_table

Comment: This won't work. If the column doesn't contain a valid date, the cast `::date` will result in an error.

Comment: if the format is invalid like this 01-032021 then the query can be used because I've tried it